# Can libraries with implementation separated from declaration benefit from constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++14, static-libraries, constexpr

Recently, I wanted to write a static library which has a class template and several non-template operator overload functions of the specific instantiation of the class template. I decided to define the class template in a.h and define the functions in a.cc. But suddenly a question occurred to me that if I declare and define the functions with `constexpr`, will the compiler be able to calculate the result at compile time(link time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, just like with template function bodies, you cannot put the definition of `constexpr` functions in different translation units from the code that consumes them. The compiler can only see what is in the current translation unit (aka: the .cpp file and everything it #includes). So if the body of the function isn't there, then it can't execute the code at compile-time.

Now, you can put them into separate files. But code using it would still have to #include both files.